# What factors you have do you count on to speculate effectively?

Tags: investing, trading, starting-out-investing, speculation

What are the factors that you consider if you want to make a thoughtful speculation decision (as thoughtful as being a speculator lets you be)?

I can only count these:

- Market trends
- Patterns on the market
- News
- Intel (as in, corporate espionage)

But I'm sure there are many more. What are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strategy would be my top factor.  While this may be implied, I do think it helps to have an idea of what is causing the buy and sell signals in speculating as I'd rather follow a strategy than try to figure things out completely from scratch that doesn't quite make sense to me.

There are generally a couple of different schools of analysis that may be worth passing along:

[Fundamental Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_analysis):Fundamental analysis of a business involves analyzing its financial statements and health, its management and competitive advantages, and its competitors and markets. When applied to futures and forex, it focuses on the overall state of the economy, interest rates, production, earnings, and management. When analyzing a stock, futures contract, or currency using fundamental analysis there are two basic approaches one can use; bottom up analysis and top down analysis. The term is used to distinguish such analysis from other types of investment analysis, such as quantitative analysis and technical analysis.

[Technical Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_analysis):In finance, technical analysis is a security analysis methodology for forecasting the direction of prices through the study of past market data, primarily price and volume. Behavioral economics and quantitative analysis use many of the same tools of technical analysis, which, being an aspect of active management, stands in contradiction to much of modern portfolio theory. The efficacy of both technical and fundamental analysis is disputed by the efficient-market hypothesis which states that stock market prices are essentially unpredictable.

There are tools like "Stock Screeners" that will let you filter based on various criteria to use each analysis in a mix.  There are various strategies one could use.  [Wikipedia under Stock Speculator lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_trader): "Several different types of stock trading strategies or approaches exist including day trading, trend following, market making, scalping (trading), momentum trading, trading the news, and arbitrage."  Thus, I'd advise research what approach are you wanting to use as the "Make it up as we go along losing real money all the way" wouldn't be my suggested approach.

There is something to be said for there being numerous columnists and newsletter peddlers if you want other ideas but I would suggest having a strategy before putting one's toe in the water.